# Form validation with exact number of characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-core

I'm trying to add a validation rule for a text field. The value should match a number consisting of digits only. Additionally, the number should be exactly 10 characters long.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression("(^[0-9]*$)", ErrorMessage = "Number must be 10 digits and contain only numbers.")]
[MinLength(10)]
[MaxLength(10)]
```

I'm guessing there is an easier way, adding to the regular expression perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine the constraint that the property can only consist of digits and must be exactly 10 characters long by using the following regular expression: `^\d{10}$`

> Matches a digit (equal to [0-9]) exactly 10 times (**[reference](https://regexr.com/4ctgm)**).

Your data annotation would look like shown below.

```
[RegularExpression("^\d{10}$", ErrorMessage = "Number must be 10 digits and contain only numbers.")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Could this do the trick?

```
[RegularExpression("(^[0-9]{10}$)", ErrorMessage = "Number must be 10 digits and contain only numbers.")]

(^[0-9]{10}$)
```

[Regex101 Reference](https://regex101.com/r/6xP0pj/2)